plink.exe "hanging" when used in PowerShell script
I have a script that removes files from a Linux server using PowerShell. The script suddenly stopped working and now it "hangs" when running this command:
$file = "file_path"

plink.exe -pw password account@server "rm $file"

I don't get any error message neither the script finish.

I'm guessing that if the command hangs, it is because it is waiting for the "server". Can you try 'ping'ing the server? If that doesn't work and you have access to PowerShell, try the following: Test-NetConnection server -port 22
If the last line of output from that command is: TcpTestSuccesseded: False then you have a network issue.

Does it output anything? Would it output anything, if you add -v?

Does this answer your question:  plink won't return to command prompt?

@iRon Shouldn't be the case with a simple rm command.

Anyways, it should be easy to exclude PowerShell from the issue by trying the command from a different terminal/console: plink.exe -pw password account@server "rm file_path". If it concerns a variable path, I suspect a special character in the path as e.g. a space ... or an ampersand (&)

What happens when you run the command interactively?

I suggest plink.exe is not returning because it oppened some kind of an interactive shell on the linux host...
Therefore waiting on a prompt.
If there was any networking issue, you would get an error after 120 sec.
Suggesting to run the plink.exe command interactively in PowerShell terminal, and see what happens.
Suggesting to inspect the relevant plink.exe documentation, especially options -v and  -batch

To at least avoid the command hanging your script, you could add a time-out.
$file = 'file_path'
$PlinkArgs = "-pw password account@server ""rm $file"""

Wait-Process (Start-Process plink.exe $PlinkArgs -PassThru).Id -TimeOut 10 #seconds

You might also consider using a try - catch statement as well to kill and log any plink commands that doesn't terminate by them self.
